# mpi4py: how is MPI.COMM_WORLD shared between files?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi, mpi4py

I have a python program that uses several files, and I want to run it in parallel using mpi4py. Do I have to define the variable comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD at the beginning of each file, or should I define it one time and pass it as an argument?

To make things concrete, consider the following program made of two python files, first <kbd>mpi_base_file.py</kbd>:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from mpi_other_file import print_rank

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

if rank == 0:
    print('rank and comm in base file', comm.Get_rank(), comm)
    print_rank()
```

and <kbd>mpi_other_file.py</kbd>:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

def print_rank():
    print('rank and comm in other file', comm.Get_rank(), comm)
```

Runing <kbd>mpiexec -np 2 python3 mpi_base_file.py</kbd>  gives:

> rank, comm and size in base file 0 <mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm object at
> 0x7fa841be49f0>
>
> rank, comm and size in other file 0 <mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm object at
> 0x7fa841be49f0>

The variable MPI.COMM_WORLD and rank seems to be the same in both files, how does mpi4py achieve that?
Does it works on several nodes that do not share the same memory? If not, what is the correct way to implement the program?

Comment: `MPI.COMM_WORLD` is a global variable defined in the `MPI` module. It does not matter which file is using it.